# Javascript not working properly in PhoneGap 3.4.0

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am new to phonegap and facing strange issuses while working on javascript and phonegap. here is the javascript that I am working on:

```
var app = {
// Application Constructor
initialize : function() {
        alert("hpslisdf");
        this.bindEvents();

},

bindEvents : function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},
// deviceready Event Handler
//
// The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
// function, we must explicity call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
onDeviceReady : function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
},
// Update DOM on a Received Event
receivedEvent : function(id) {
    // alert("inside received");
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');
    alert("received event");
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
    alert("after filesystem");

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
}
};

function gotFS(fileSystem) {

// var reader = fileSystem.root.createReader();
// reader.readEntries(gotList, fail);
var sdcard = fileSystem.root;
// alert(sdcard.value);
sdcard.getDirectory('dcim/camera', {
    create : false
}, function(dcim) {
    // alert(dcim.value);
    var directoryReader = dcim.createReader();
//  alert("hs");
    directoryReader.readEntries(function(entries) {
        for (var i = 0; i <1 ; i++) {
            //entries.length
            // alert(entries.length);
            entries[i].file(function(f) {

                // alert(entries[i]);
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
                    // alert("xxxxxx");
                    var url = evt.target.result;// base64 data uri
                    // alert("now");
                    // var img = $('<img id="dynamic>'); //Equivalent:
                    // $(document.createElement('img'))
                    // var img=$('#dynamic');
                    // img.attr('value','')
                    // img.attr('src', url);
                    // img.appendTo('#imagediv');
                //  $('#imagediv').html('hiiiii').show();
                    // imagediv.attr('value','hiiiii');
                //  alert("hello");
                    var imagediv = document.getElementById("imagediv");
                imagediv.innerHTML = "hiytrud";
                //  var elem = document.createElement("img");
                    //elem.src = url;
                    //imagediv.appendChild(elem);

                    // alert(url);
                    // console.log(url)
                    // reader.abort();
                };

                reader.readAsDataURL(f);
            },
                    function(error) {
                        console("Unable to retrieve file properties: "
                                + error.code);

                    });

        }

    }, function(e) {
        console.log(e.code);
    });

}, function(error) {
    console.log(error.code);
});
}

function fail(evt) {
alert("fail");
console.log(evt.target.error.code);
}
```

Now the first problem that I am facing is that I see most of the alerts twice but the app.initialize method is called only once in my html code. and the gotFS() is not getting called . Now most of you will say that the problem lies in the following line:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
```

but I have added the `fileSystem` and `FileTransfer` plugins. Also the control reaches to the very next line and I can see the alert of the next line i.e. "after filesystem" but this alert comes only a single time. and the gotFS method or fail method doesnt get loaded at all. I dont know what I am doing wrong Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Two obvious reasons why it might not work are:

1. The callback methods are not defined.
2. You are trying testing it in browser/web emulator.

Can you provide code for callbacks and make sure the can be called without errors from receivedEvent?

Comment: @jtf please look the code again.. I have defined both of the call back  methods that are gotFS and fail. And I am tesing it on my tablet using phonegap app for developers.